# Can't access localhost or phpMyAdmin with WAMP

Tags: localhost, wamp

I'm running Apache v2.2.21, PHP v5.38, and MySQL v5.5.16. The WAMP icon is green.

As the post title says, I can't access either localhost or phpMyAdmin from the WAMP systray icon menu, nor can I by typing http://127.0.0.1/index.php in a browser.

Clicking on either localhost or phpMyAdmin gives me the error message "Unable to connect - Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1."

I do have Skype and I know there are issues with Skype and WAMP port conflicts, so I quit Skype, and tried it, but got the same results.

At first the WAMP icon was always orange, but some searching here revealed that changing the listening port to 8080 (the default is 80) in httpd.conf. That got the orange icon to go green.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it.

The last paragraph in my post was the key: I went into Skype and unchecked the "Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections." Then I went back into the httpd.conf file and changed "Listen 8080" back to the original "Listen 80".

Now both Skype and WAMP work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that version of Wamp is special for joomla sites, You can only access the database(php myadmin) if you are logged in in the back end of Joomla CMS(Content Management System). To solve this you can just download a blue icon Wamp.