# After I install Wampserver2, while opening phpmyadmin i got error Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, localhost, wampserver

After I install Wampserver2,

1. while opening phpmyadmin i got error "Unable to connect
   **Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.**
   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
   moments.
   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
   connection.
   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
   that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
2. Apache > Service > Test port 80 : **Your port 80 is not actually used.**
   also tried Apache > Service > install service : But Apache > Service > Start/resume 
   service is still disabled.

   C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\host file has the statement 127.0.0.1       localhost

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have the latest version of both of these Microsoft C++ Redistributable runtime libraries.

The 2008 Redist is used by wampmanager
The 2010 Redist is used by Apache

FOR WAMP 32bit
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) 
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)

FOR WAMP 64bit
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64) 
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no other program conflict Wamp such as IIS, Microsoft Web Deploy, SQL, Skype, Zonealarm, firewall/antivirus, NOD32, Eset, any web related program including Remote Desktop, Teamviewer or Apache, MySQL, PHP outside wamp folder (ie. in Program Files or System32 folder) ...

IIS and Apache/Wamp are both web server and might conflict in some way, so you have to disable IIS in order for Wamp to work

Disable IIS in Vista/W7:

Control Panel, Uninstall Programs, Turn Widows Features On or Off, uncheck Internet Information Services

Disable IIS in XP:

Control Panel, Add/Remove Programs, Add/Remove Windows Components, uncheck Internet Information Services (IIS)

Restart computer, then restart Wamp

Also, in folder C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc, open file hosts and delete anything in this file and have only this line below and nothing else

127.0.0.1 localhost

If using Skype, open Skype > Tools > Options > Advanced > Connection then uncheck "use port 80..." restart Wamp then Skype

Also you can try

> I went into Skype and unchecked the "Use port 80 and 443 as
>   alternatives for incoming connections." Then I went back into the
>   httpd.conf file and changed "Listen 8080" back to the original "Listen
>   80".

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974388/cant-access-localhost-or-phpmyadmin-with-wamp)

Comment: * There is no Skype or IIS installed on my pc.

Comment: firewall/antivirus,Remote Desktop is there on my pc

Comment: how to check this program conflict with wamp ?

Comment: check whether wamp on the task bar is green or yellow.

Comment: it is converted to orange from magenta.

Comment: I install vcredist_x86 - Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) and then reinstall wamp server, and now it is green. and phpmyadmin page is working now.

Comment: Thanks Dasun for replying.

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.