# Localhost is not working in wampserver

Tags: wampserver

Already i installed Wampserver, that time it works correctly. A  few days back i try to open localhost, it displays "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost
Did you mean: localhost.­net". I don't know the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to start Apache server.For that,you have to right click Wamp icon.Then click start Apache.After this is done,enter localhost in the url.It displays a message 'It Works!.
Hope this resolves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually start the server first.

That is you have to start Apache sever, then enter localhost in the url

To start double click on the Xampp icon. Then manually click on the start button for apache, mysql and other features which you need like tomcat and filezilla. Dont close it but just minimize it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have skype running? If so close it so its not running at all and restart wamp.

Skype uses port 8080 which Wamp uses too. switching the ports would fix this.

Heres a previous Q/A

[Can't access localhost or phpMyAdmin with WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974388/cant-access-localhost-or-phpmyadmin-with-wamp)

Answer (score 0):

For a WAMP server, just run the application and you will see an icon in the taskbar from which you can manage certain properties. That said, so long as the server is running, localhost should be working.

Answer (score 0):

You must did not run the apache server first.
You should click the icon of the wamp , then click start apache. 
Hope that helps.